# Why are execution plans wildly different when selecting 1000 rows vs 2000?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Consider the queries below.  The only difference is 1000 vs 2000 rows returned.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 lwa.Message INTO #foo
FROM dbo.LogWidgetsAPI lwa (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY lwa.TimeStamp
```

vs

```
SELECT TOP 2000 lwa.Message INTO #foo
FROM dbo.LogWidgetsAPI lwa (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY lwa.TimeStamp
```

However, 1000 rows are returned in under a second, while the query with 2000 rows takes significantly longer.

The query plan for the first query is reasonably simple:

[image]

but the 2nd query is using parallelization:
[image]

What would using just 1k rows more force parallelization?

P.S.  The table contains over 6 million records and TimeStamp column is indexed.

Comment: What is the cost threshold for parallelism setting, and what are the costs for both plans?

Comment: Because your [cost threshold for parallelism](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/why-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-shouldnt-be-set-to-5/) is low?

Comment: @JacobH For query with 1000 rows the `Estimated Subtree Cost` is 6.63.  For query with 2000 rows, it's 9.03.  The `Cost Threshold for Parallelism` is 12 and `Max Degree of Parallelism` is 4.

Comment: As a simple test, try adding `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to the end of your second query, and see what your timing looks like. When you get right down to it, there are many things that can slow down a query with more rows, from insufficient free memory to insufficient free CPUs to cover your parallelism.

Comment: @LaughingVergil I did.  That brings the performance back to the level of the 1st query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per other comments, it sounds like the cost threshold for parallelism is too low, and is making queries go parallel even when the process to do so/ gather the streams makes your process take longer.

Try setting that to 50, or experimenting with different numbers.

Also, worth a read: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/why-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-shouldnt-be-set-to-5/